# Custom UITableViewCell does not appear on second load

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a custom uitableview with custom uitableviewcell in my view cell. The cell doesn't show on second load. That is, when I go from this view to another and back to this view.

This is how I load my table in my view.

```
CropTableViewController *cropTblViewCon = [[CropTableViewController alloc]init];
 self.cropTableViewController = cropTblViewCon;
cropTableViewController.view.frame = cropTblView.frame;
[cropTblView removeFromSuperview];  
[self.view addSubview:cropTableViewController.view];
self.cropTblView = cropTableViewController.tableView;
```

This is how I go another view

```
AppDelegate_iPhone *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
AddPestReportStepOne *report = [[AddPestReportStepOne alloc]init];
[appDelegate.navCon pushViewController:report animated: YES];   
[report release];
```

This is how I load my table cell in my custom table view.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCropCell";    
CustomCropCell *cell = (CustomCropCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
//  tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                              loadNibNamed:@"CustomCropCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){

        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell = (CustomCropCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}
//if (counter<6 ) {

CropEntity *crop = [[CropEntity alloc] init];
crop=[ cropList objectAtIndex:counter];

NSString *imgStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",domainName,cropImagePath, [crop cropImage]];    
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgStr]]];
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(80, 80);
[cell setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
image = [Utilities scale:image toSize:size ];
[cell.columnOne setTag: [[crop cropId] integerValue] ];
[cell.columnOne setTitle:[crop cropName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.columnOne setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.columnOne setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, -image.size.width, -75.0, 0.0)]; // Left inset is the negative of image width. counter = counter+ 1;
[cell.columnOne setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.columnOne setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-15.0, 0.0, 0.0, -cell.columnOne.titleLabel.bounds.size.width)]; // Right inset is the negative of text bounds width.   
[cell.columnOne setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
counter = counter + 1;
```

It seems that the rows are not removed. My cellforrowat indexpath keep increasing...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i'm assuming you want to add a UITableView to a ViewController.  Here are the steps for this:

(1) You have create an UIViewController, whether by code or interface builder

(2) Create an UITableView, and add it to your UIViewController

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] 
                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 440) 
                          style:UITableViewStylePlain];

// Set up the tableView delegate and datasource

[self.view addSubview:tableView];

[tableView release];
```

I'm sure there is a reason why you are adding the tableView to a UIViewController (there is not reason to have an extra UITableViewController.  If not just use a UITableViewController, and set up a UITableView.

Also, keep in mind where you create the tableView at.  For instance, if you create it in init or viewDidLoad and using a UINavigationController, when you hit the back button on the UINavigationController the ViewDidLoad or init isn't getting called.  Try it yourself, put a NSLog statement to test.

So either use viewDidAppear or [tableView reloadData];

Edit:

Think about your code you create a UITableViewContoller then you remove its UITableView from it's super view (does not make sense) and then you add the UITableViewControllers view (the UITableView) to self.view which is i'm guessing a UIViewController.  Surely this can't be what you are trying to do.

I would recommend reading Apple's View Programming guide for a better understanding of UIViewControllers and Views.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html